# Perspective with google map or bing image

Tags: gimp, transform

I have a common google map image and I would like to transform to a one-point perspective changing its shape to a trapezoid filled with the original map.
The new map would have streets and building footprint also transformed. I have been testing the transformation tools of Gimp 2.8.22 but I do not get the desired result. 
Is there any possible tool to do it? and how I could use it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The proper tool for this is the [Perspective tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-perspective.html). You get this kind of result:

[image]

You can also try `Filters>Map>Map to object` (mapping to plane) .